# Sending email to selected users using django

Tags: python, django, email, django-views, django-queryset

I want to send mails for the only users whose batch and department is matching with that of request's batch and department.Batch and department are in OneToOne relation with the user.The mail should be send from this function.That is mail should be send when the boolean field is_principal is true.Here is my code.

models.py

```
class Rep(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dept = models.ForeignKey(Departement, default=0)
    batch = models.ForeignKey(Batch, default=0)
    semester = models.ForeignKey(Semester, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
             return str(self.user)
class Retest(models.Model):

   semester = models.ForeignKey(Semester)
   dept = models.ForeignKey(Departement)
   batch = models.ForeignKey(Batch)
   date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
   subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   admnno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   reason = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   proof = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   is_hod = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_principal = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   notify = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_sure = models.BooleanField(default=False)

   def get_absolute_url(self):
             return reverse( 'retest:retestform')
   def __str__(self):
             return self.name
```

views.py

```
def accepted(request, retest_id):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        retest.is_principal = True
        retest.save(update_fields=['is_principal'])
        email = EmailMessage('RMS', 'Your Notifications are Pending.', to=[.email])
        email.send()
return render(request, 'retest/request.html' , {'retest': retest})
```

How can I set the conditions for the to address?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def accepted(request, retest_id):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        retest.is_principal = True
        retest.save(update_fields=['is_principal'])

        users = [rep.user for rep in Rep.objects.filter(
            batch=retest.batch, department=retest.dept
        )]
        for user in users:
        user.email_user(subject='RMS', message='Your Notifications are Pending.')

    return render(request, 'retest/request.html' , {'retest': retest})
```

Comment: Double check your [SMTP configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/)

Answer (score 0):

If you sure about your code is 100% perfect and email is not working. Then singin to your mail. Then Try. It will work. If you are using gmail as your email host, Gmail block this type of actions , beacause gmail is not designed for that. Use some other mail services like elastic mail or something to work properly. 
[Email in Django not working sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710717/email-in-django-not-working-sometimes). You mensioned the same problem in this qtn also.